# 'I says' in spoken English

Tags: speech, conversation

Is it popular to use 'I says' in conversations in spoken English?
Especially when we talk about the past in the present.

- "Hey, John do you remember Linda?"
- "Yeh"
- "We were talking yesterday and she says, how's John?"
- "And I says, oh, he's okay, and then she says, are you still friends?"
- "I says, sure."

Comment: About 550,000 results for "I says" found on the web, including (esp. transcripts of speech); About 452,000 results in GoogleBooks -- Has been in use all the time:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i+says&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ci%20says%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Popeye, I think, used it. So if you want to sound like Popeye ...

Comment: Popeye the sailor?

Comment: Yes.  Anything wrong with "I said"?

Comment: @aparente001 It's different.

Comment: If you care to share a bit more about this, I might be able to be more helpful.

Comment: I often hear in movies and TV series that people in conversation say **"i Says"** instead of **I say, I said**

Comment: To me, this makes the speaker sound as if they live in a poorer or more rural part of Britain. This doesn't sound like something an American would say but I have heard it lots in Britain, particularly in older settings. For instance, going from memory, I imagine Dick Van Dyke uses this a lot in Mary Poppins.

Comment: @Kris -- those ngram results are misleading. Even from 1800 many are high-class authors writing the halting imaginary dialect of low-class characters. Top 1810 example: "So I says, says I, my Lord, says I, if your Lordship i'n't engaged particularly, my father is a silversmith." These aren't good evidence for "should I speak this way / do people speak this way."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While "I says" appears often in spoken, informal speech, it is also often used as an example of extremely (excessively?) casual language -- almost a stereotype of a relaxed storytelling mode in which proper speech does not matter.

"I says" was a staple of Vaudeville comedy routines -- the fact that the speech is slightly wrong / informal helps to characterize the speaker as lower class / foolish, and make the story funnier. When you find "I says" in this kind of writing you often find it alongside a combination of informality / slang and silly grammatical mistakes, like improper verb conjugation. Popeye the Sailor also uses this kind of speech a lot, with wild grammatical errors reflecting both his lack of education and his relaxed confidence.

Here is a Vaudeville example:

> I says to him, says I, “Mully, ould boy, will you have the kindness to fetch me in the mustard?” An' he was a long time bringin' it, an' I oppertuned him for kapin' me ... (Choice Dialect and Vaudeville Stage Jokes, 1902, p 109).

Currently a huge number of the recent search results hits for "I says" are all related to ["so I says"](https://www.google.com/search?q="so+I+says"). These memes (including images, animations, video clips, etc.) are almost all inspired by a brief scene from The Simpsons which played on Bart using the casual, know-nothing style of storytelling that is a historical throwback to old Vaudeville: "So I says to Mabel, I says."

Answer (score -1):

I have friends who use this, but only when recounting an incident or telling a story. It's almost like speaking in the third person.